# CSS with Anchor text

Tags: css, anchor

here is the issue. I have put an anchor in page. But this anchor doesn't have `href` attribute:

```
<a onClick="javascript:submit(10);" onMouseOver="adjust(1)" onMouseOut="adjust(0)">Click Here</a>
```

This works just fine. But I want to have it underlined all the time, and I achieved it by:

```
a
{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Now I want `Click Here` to have a different color than the default (black). And I want, when mouse over the color changes, and returns back to what I set when mouse is not over. Also, I want to change the background same as text color.

How can I achieve this?

PS: I`ve been googling for this for nearly 2 hours now and can't find anything!!

***UPDATE:***

This is my current CSS regarding the anchor

```
a, a:link, a:active, a:visited {
    color: #00f;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover {
    color: #f00;    /* Red */
    background-color: #000;    /* Black */
}
```

Comment: Always add a `href` attribute, like `<a href="#">...</a>`. Otherwise, your code won't be valid, and from my experience Chrome won't even consider it as an anchor.

Comment: @ldiqual: added href to one of the anchors and it worked. But the problem, I don't want anything to be on the status bar now.

Comment: You didn't talk about a status bar. What do you mean ?

Answer (score 4):

`color` attribute can be used to set color to the text. Try this -

```
a
{
    text-decoration:underline;
    color: Red;
}

a:hover { color: Blue; }
```

Comment: I did but I only get the underline colored, not the text. I fixed it, I had an h1 inside with text, I had to put the anchor tag inside the h1. Not this: `<a><h1>text here</h1></a>` ❌❗️⚠️, but Like this `<h1><a>text here</a></h1>`  This is the one that worked.

Answer (score 2):

To give the `<a>` a different text colour, use the `color` attribute:

```
a {
    color: #f00;    /* Red */
}
```

To change the style when the mouse hovers over the `<a>`, use the `:hover:` pseudo class, with `background-color` to change the background:

```
a:hover {
    color: #00f;    /* Blue */
    background-color: #000;    /* Black */
}
```

When the mouse is moved away from the element, the `:hover` pseudo class will be "removed" automatically, defaulting the `<a>` back to it's original style.

Comment: You need to be more descriptive; tell me _how_ it's not working, and please post any CSS that's applied to the `<a>` element in your original question by editing it.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other CSS applied to parent elements (therefore applied to the `<a>`) that might be overriding the CSS you set explicitly _for_ the `<a>`?

Comment: nope, I have a popup that is shown when a specific element is clicked. But not applied to the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

```
a, a:link, a:active, a:visited {
    color: #00f;
    cursor: pointer;
}
a:hover {
    color: #0ff;
}
```

Comment: On some browsers, the `:hover` pseudoclass needs to be declared between the `:visited` and `:active` pseudoclasses to function, forcing you to select the different states of `a` in this order: `a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active`. You might also try removing the `a,`(`a` + `,`) from the first declaration.